# ViewModel launch and withContext unresolved reference

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, androidx, lifecycle

I was using the viewModelScope to launch a coroutine then the withContext to use it on a separate thread.

Suddenly, without chaning anything to the code I get "undefined reference" for launch and withContext

I tried to run "Invalidate Caches / Restart", reinstalled the app, restarted everything.
The class extends the ViewModel()

[image]

My gradle file looks like this:

```
def lifecycle_version = "2.2.0"

// ViewModel
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
// LiveData
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
// Lifecycles only (without ViewModel or LiveData)
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
// Saved state module for ViewModel
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:$lifecycle_version"

implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"
```

Comment: did you found solution to it?

Comment: I don't remember the exact fix but I think the dependencies were not synchronized